# Listen for a webhook server side using meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, routes

I've set up a meteor app using `iron-router` and I want the app to listen to a webhook from another service (basically I'm building an API for other services to use)

So for example, when an external website calls `myapp.meteor.com/webhook` I want to catch that specific link and parameters and do stuff with the data.

Update: Thanks to a comment I found this: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing

```
Router.route('/webhooks', { where: 'server' })
  .post(function () {
    console.log(this);
    this.response.end('Caught you\n');
    //this.response.status(200).json({text:"Todo added"});
});
```

I added the above in the `/server` folder as there is no need to for the front-end server to worry about this like mentioned in the comment. But when I load this using `postman` POST request, it just returns my HTML for `not found`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

*UPDATE*
I tried what @David said and still I get the template loaded and nothing in the console. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Code in router]

Comment: You just need to create a [server-side route](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#server-routing). Was there something more specific you wanted to know?

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks for that, got one step closer but still can't get it to work. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server route will only run if no client routes also match. I suspect you have a catch-all route which is executing on the client and preventing the server route from running. One solution is to define all of the routes in a common folder like `/lib` so that you can properly order them. Your routes file could look something like:

- client route 1
- client route 2
- server route 1
- server route 2
- catch-all (not found) route

Comment: Humm...I moved it up into my main router but still no luck. See main question for updated printscreen.

Comment: That syntax worked for me. How are you testing it? I did: `curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/webhooks/abc123"`. If you don't actually do a POST request, or if you forget to add a `source` parameter, the route won't run and you'll get a client-side response.